# Array of integers which appear to be objects

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a strange situation which I do not understand. I wand to use an array as indices.

```
batch_index = np.arange(min(mb_size,len(D)), dtype=np.int32)
Q_target[batch_index, actions] = rewards + gamma*np.max(Q_next, axis=1)*dones
```

But when I run this I get an error:

> IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean)
> type

It appears to be an array of objects:

```
In: actions
Out: array([2, 2, 2, 2], dtype=object)
```

The same in variable explorer:

> Type: Array of object Value: ndarray object of numpy module

In the same time:

```
In:type(actions[0])
Out: numpy.int64
```

I know that I can use:

```
actions = np.array(actions, dtype=np.int32)
```

But I do not understand why do I have to do it.

P.S. here is how I get `actions`

```
D = deque()
D.append((state, action, reward, state_new, done))
#type(action) == int64
minibatch = np.array(random.sample(D, min(mb_size,len(D))))
actions = minibatch[:,1]
```

Comment: `actions.dtype`?

Comment: actions.dtype returns dtype('O')

Comment: Then `actions` cannot be used (directly) as an index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion it's because `actions` is of mixed type (i.e. `done` is Boolean, `reward` is most probably some sort of numeric etc.) because you get it from `queue` object.
In python in general, and specifically in NumPy, when you have a mixed, non-numeric object types - the array is cast to an Object (or other unifying type, that all items agree on). So in your case, the reason you can't index the data with this array is not due to the `batch_index`, but because of the `actions` array.